# Delete node from select/combo javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

```
RSS Channels
Add RSS to List: <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
<input type="button" value="Add " onclick="addCombo()">
<input type="button" value="Delete " onclick="delCombo()">
<br/>
Existing Channels : <select name="combo" id="combo"></select>



    var select = document.createElement("select");
    var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage";
    option.value = "http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage";
    currentRSS="http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage"
    combo.add(option, null);


   function delCombo() {
        var combo = document.getElementById("combo");
        alert("Current Channel " + currentRSS);
        combo.remove(currentRSS);
        alert("Delete Channel " + currentRSS);

        numberRSSChannels--;
        document.getElementById("stat1").textContent="Numbers of RSS Channels " + numberRSSChannels;
        document.getElementById("combo").value="";
        currentRSS="";
        changeRSS();
    }
```

I need make option to add and to remove some option in my select menu.
Its very simple to add, but not to delete.

When I try to delete some node from select/combo like in example it always deletes the first one.
How to delete `currentRSS`?

Comment: what errors you have? Did you research for this question? please show us how you tried to acomplish this. Please read this [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easyest way to do it is using jQuery:

```
$('#combo option[value="' + currentValue '"]').remove();
```

You need to add reference to jquery in your page. As an alternative, you can loop over the options of the combo:

```
var combo = document.getElementById("combo");
var options = combo.options;
for (var index = 0; index < options.length; index ++) {
  if (options[index].value == currentValue) {
    combo.removeChild(options[index]);
  }
}
```